# Global custom jQuery-validator method issue with multiple forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, portal

I have multiple forms on a single HTML page. Each form will have different validation logic for same method name. However, jQuery-validator only allows method to be added globally, such as the one below for method 'equal':

```
$.validator.methods.equal = function(value, element, param) {
    // form1 logic
    return value == param;
};
```

I tried jQuery.noConflict() but this does not stop form2's method to override form1's.

The reason for the need, I am developing portal application with multiple portlets. Each portlet is like independent web-application (But without HTML, HEAD, BODY tags, just fragment of HTML). Each portlet is not aware of each other. Together they form a single HTML page, portal will combine all portlets HTML fragment and add common HTML, HEAD, BODY tags.

I need either a way to allow multiple instance of jQuery or multiple instance of jQuery-validator or way to declare the custom validator method non-globally.

Helps appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly hack, but you could put the portlets in iframes. Each iframe runs javascript in isolation. You could have multiple "instances" of jquery.

iFrames cause all kinds of other problems, though, so this is a last-resort solution.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't do because it is a portlet application